# In Java9 how can I reflectively load a class if I don't know it's module?

Tags: java, reflection, java-9

Suppose I have an application that given a well known package name and class, I need to load that class reflectively and invoke some methods from it. Let's say this class is available in another java jar (the "library").

So far, before java 9, since all the classes in the classpath were available, it was straightforward to achieve this.

However, with Java 9, if the application "module" does not require the "library" package, the library class is not accessible.

How can I achieve the same behavior using modularized jars?

Example:

This is my application:

```
// This is defined in ReflectionApp.jar
// ReflectionApp
// └── src
//     ├── module-info.java
//     └── org
//         └── reflection
//             └── app
//                 └── ReflectionApp.java
//
package org.reflection.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectionApp {
    private static final String PACKAGE = "org.reflection.lib";
    private static final String CLASS = "ReflectiveClass";
    private static final String METHOD = "doSomeWork";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // This will not work using java9
        Class<?> klass = Class.forName(String.format("%s.%s", PACKAGE, CLASS));
        Object obj = klass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        Method meth = klass.getDeclaredMethod(METHOD);
        meth.invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

And this is my library

```
// This is defined in ReflectionLib.jar
// ReflectionLib
// └── src
//     ├── module-info.java
//     └── org
//         └── reflection
//             └── lib
//                 └── ReflectiveClass.java
//
package org.reflection.lib;

public class ReflectiveClass {

    public void doSomeWork() {
        System.out.println("::: Doing some work!");
    }
}
```

At the moment if I try to call it like this (assuming all jars are created and available in lib directory):

`java --module-path lib -m ReflectionApp/org.reflection.app.ReflectionApp`

Then I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reflection.lib.ReflectiveClass`

--- SOLUTION ---

Thanks to @Nicolai I was able to make it run by adding `--add-modules` parameter to the command.

```
⇒  java --module-path lib --add-modules ReflectionLib -m ReflectionApp/org.reflection.app.ReflectionApp
::: Doing some work!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [plenty of ways to make reflection work](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/) but none of them are as straight-forward as the "it just works" way before the module system. Let me narrow them down for your particular problem.

But before that you have to make sure that the *library* module actually makes it into the module graph. If it is not transitively required by the initial module, you can use `--add-modules library` to add it to the graph.

### Package Exported

You write that "if the application 'module' does not require the 'library' package, the library class is not accessible". Assuming you meant *module* instead of *package* that is true but does not apply here. Accessibility builds on two things:

1. a reads-edge between the two modules
2. the accessed module exporting the accessed types

You didn't write anything regarding 2. but if `module library { exports org.reflection.lib; }`, then you are free to use reflection. The reason is that the reads edge is added automatically when you start using the reflection API.

### Types Not Accessible

Now it gets more interesting. If the *library* module does not export `org.reflection.lib` or if `ReflectiveClass` were not public, the above approach does not work. In that case you have plenty of options to choose from:

- make the type public and export the package (possibly only to the accessing module)
- open the package (possibly only to the accessing module) or the module
- add command line options to achieve any of the above

To see how they compare have a look at this article about [reflection vs encapsulation in Java 9](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/#choiceofweapons).

Comment: Would you edit your answer to mention that --add-modules could be used to fix the 'ClassNotFoundException'? Then I can accept it.

Comment: Done. I didn't see the `ClassNotFoundException` in your question before. Jumped straight into answering the reflection part. (Oops.)

Answer (score 1):

If the first module does not depend on the second module via the `requires` clause in `module-info.java`, then the second module is not in the transitive closure of the first module's dependencies. Therefore the second module is not observable to the runtime and your reflection fails. In this case, you can explicitly add your module to the module graph via `--add-modules` option:

```
--add-modules <module-name>
```

In your case `<module-name>` should be substituted with the name of the `ReflectionLib` module.

Comment: The reflection API automatically adds that reads edge, so doing it manually from the command line does not change anything.

Comment: @Nicolai Are you sure? I just checked reflection without `requires`. It throws `ClassNotFoundException`. If I add `requires`, the exception disappears.

Comment: A `ClassNotFoundError` is thrown when the class is really not there - when it is but reflection fails, you get an `IllegalAccessException`. Your error implies that the module containing the class did not make it into the module graph, most likely because it was not required. Use `--add-modules` to make sure it's there. Have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-reflection) for details.

Comment: @Nicolai Thanks, I tried with --add-modules and it works like a charm :)